# Get only the matching values and corresponding fields from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

In elasticsearch, let's say I have documents like

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "department": "Biology",
  "address": "445 Mount Eden Road"
},
{
  "name": "Jane",
  "department": "Chemistry",
  "address": "32 Wilson Street"
},
{
  "name": "Laura",
  "department": "BioTechnology",
  "address": "21 Greens Road"
},
{
  "name": "Mark",
  "department": "Physics",
  "address": "Random UNESCO Bio-reserve"
}
```

There is a use-case where, if I type "bio" in a search bar, I should get the matching field-value(s) from elasticsearch along with the field name.

For this example,

**Input**: "bio"

**Expected Output**:

```
{
  "field": "department",
  "value": "Biology"
},
{
  "field": "department",
  "value": "BioTechnology"
},
{
  "field": "address",
  "value": "Random UNESCO Bio-reserve"
}
```

What type of query should I use? I can think of using NGram Tokenizer and then use match query. But, I am not sure how shall I get only the matching field value (not the entire document) and the corresponding field name as the output.

Answer (score 0):

After reading further about [Completion Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/search-suggesters-completion.html) and [Context Suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/suggester-context.html), I could solve this problem in the following way:

1) Keep a separate "suggest" field for each record with type "completion" with context-mapping of type "category". The mapping I created looks like as follows:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "suggest": {
      "type": "completion",
      "contexts": [
        {
          "name": "field_type",
          "type": "category",
          "path": "cat"
        }
      ]
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "department": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

2) Then I insert the records as shown below (adding search metadata to the "suggest" field with proper "context").

For example, to insert the first record, I execute the following:

**POST:  localhost:9200/test_index/test_type/1**

```
{
    "suggest": [
        {
            "input": ["john"],
            "contexts": {
                "field_type": ["name"] 
            }
        },
        {
            "input": ["biology"],
            "contexts": {
                "field_type": ["department"] 
            }
        },
        {
            "input": ["445 mount eden road"],
            "contexts": {
                "field_type": ["address"] 
            }
        }
    ],
    "name": "john",
    "department": "biology",
    "address": "445 mount eden road"
}
```

3) If we want to search terms occurring in the middle of a sentence (as the search-term "bio" occurs in middle of the address field in the 4th record, we can index the entry as follows:

**POST:  localhost:9200/test_index/test_type/4**

```
{
    "suggest": [
        {
            "input": ["mark"],
            "contexts": {
                "field_type": ["name"] 
            }
        },
        {
            "input": ["physics"],
            "contexts": {
                "field_type": ["department"] 
            }
        },
        {
            "input": ["random unesco bio-reserve", "bio-reserve"],
            "contexts": {
                "field_type": ["address"] 
            }
        }
    ],
    "name": "mark",
    "department": "physics",
    "address": "random unesco bio-reserve"
}
```

4) Then search for the keyword "bio" like this:

**localhost:9200/test_index/test_type/_search**

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "suggest": {
        "suggestion" : {
            "text" : "bio",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest",
                "size": 10,
                "contexts": {
                    "field_type": [ "name", "department", "address" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response:

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "suggest": {
        "suggestion": [
            {
                "text": "bio",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 3,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "bio-reserve",
                        "_index": "test_index",
                        "_type": "test_type",
                        "_id": "4",
                        "_score": 1,
                        "contexts": {
                            "field_type": [
                                "address"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "biology",
                        "_index": "test_index",
                        "_type": "test_type",
                        "_id": "1",
                        "_score": 1,
                        "contexts": {
                            "field_type": [
                                "department"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "biotechnology",
                        "_index": "test_index",
                        "_type": "test_type",
                        "_id": "3",
                        "_score": 1,
                        "contexts": {
                            "field_type": [
                                "department"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest any better approach?